# Linking two tables generated from "rails generate Scaffold" (New to Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding, scaffold

I would like to save a person's information like Education, Address, etc into database tables.

If I generate Person Table(with Education) using Scaffold - id is automatically generated as primary key.

I would like to generate another table called Address for the same person using Scaffold. How can I link the id of Address table to id of Person table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want person to have_many addresses -see the rails guide for more on associations http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association

You can scaffold this by doing

```
Rails g scaffold Address person:references line1:string city:string etc
```

This will generate another model, Address, with a foreign key person_id to say which person it belongs to.

Comment: I am looking for has_one relationship. I am wondering if there is a way not to have person_id and id in Address. The id in Address is person_id.

Comment: It's generally best to keep to the "rails way" unless you have a very specific reason not to. The same migration will let you have a has_one relation.